# How to reverse a Map in Kotlin?

Tags: dictionary, kotlin, bimap

I am trying to reverse a Map in Kotlin. So far, I have come up with:

```
mapOf("foo" to 42)
  .toList()
  .map { (k, v) -> v to k }
  .toMap()
```

Is there any better way of doing this without using a middleman(middlelist)?

Answer (score 69, accepted):

Since the `Map` consists of `Entry`s and it is not `Iterable` you can use [Map#entries](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/-map/entries.html) instead.  It will be mapped to [Map#entrySet](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#entrySet--) to create a backed view of `Set<Entry>`, for example:

```
val reversed = map.entries.associateBy({ it.value }) { it.key }
```

**OR** use [Iterable#associate](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/associate.html), which will create additional `Pair`s.

```
val reversed = map.entries.associate{(k,v)-> v to k}
```

**OR** using [Map#forEach](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/for-each.html#foreach):

```
val reversed = mutableMapOf<Int, String>().also {
    //     v-- use `forEach` here     
    map.forEach { (k, v) -> it.put(v, k) } 
}.toMap()
// ^--- you can add `toMap()` to create an immutable Map.
```

Comment: So to answer the question of "Is there any better way of doing this without using a middleman (middlelist)?" the answer is no? :P

Comment: @aug yeah. I'll answer the question further.

Comment: for the last solution "it[v] = k" is more compact and expressive than it.put(v, k)

Comment: What if the given map is not a 1to1 mapping ? What if the values aren't distinct enough to serve as keys ?
The output of such operation will in general be a `Map<V, List<K>>`, where `K` is the key type and `V` the value type of the input map.

Answer (score 6):

Here is a simple extension function that reverse a map - without generating unneeded garbage (like pairs, intermediate data structures and unnecessary closures )

```
fun <K, V> Map<K, V>.reversed() = HashMap<V, K>().also { newMap ->
    entries.forEach { newMap.put(it.value, it.key) }
}
```

note that `apply` is inlined, and `entries.forEach` is also inlined (which is not the same for `Map::forEach`)

Answer (score 5):

If you need to reverse a multimap like `m: Map<K, List<V>>` to a `Map<V, List<K>>` you can do

```
m
  .flatMap { it.value.map { oneValue -> oneValue to it.key } }
  .groupBy({ it.first }, { it.second })
  .toMap()
```

In sequence,

- `mapOf('a' to listOf('b', 'c'), 'd' to listOf('b'))`
  gets flat mapped to a sequence like
- `listOf('b' to 'a', 'c' to 'a', 'b' to 'd')` which gets grouped to
- `listOf('b' to listOf('a', 'd'), 'c' to listOf('a'))` which then gets converted to a map.

This probably creates intermediate objects.

Answer (score 4):

In case your map is not a 1-1 mapping and you want the inversion to be a list of values:

```
mapOf(1 to "AAA", 2 to "BBB", 3 to "BBB").toList()
        .groupBy { pair -> pair.second } // Pair<Int, String>
        .mapValues { entry -> 
          entry.value.map { it.first } // Entry<String, List<Pair<Int, String>>
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm still learning the ins and outs of Kotlin, but I had the same requirement and as of Kotlin 1.2 it appears that you can iterate over a Map and so map() it directly like this:

```
@Test
fun testThatReverseIsInverseOfMap() {
    val intMap = mapOf(1 to "one", 2 to "two", 3 to "three")
    val revMap = intMap.map{(k,v) -> v to k}.toMap()
    assertTrue(intMap.keys.toTypedArray() contentEquals revMap.values.toTypedArray())
    assertTrue(intMap.values.toTypedArray() contentEquals revMap.keys.toTypedArray())
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is my take on a 1:1 map

```
    private fun <K, V> Map<K, V>.reverseOneToOneMap(): Map<V, K> {
        val result = this.entries.associateBy({ it.value }) { it.key }
        if (result.size != this.size) {
            throw RuntimeException("Map must be 1:1")
        }
        return result
    }
```